# Error in jQuery If...Else Statement

Tags: jquery

Could someone please find the error in this code? My entire website, except the body styling, disappears when I run it with this broken jQuery code. My website is too large to post the entire html, css, jq code...
Suggestions on better code for what I wanna do with the code below are very much welcome. The code first activates dragging for .Box1, .Box2... Then it animates to move to a different position. I just wanna toggle .smartBox to go to point A when clicked, and when clicked again back to point B.

Thanks in advance.

```js
/* .smartBox on click: actiave dragging */
    var smartBoxClicked = false;
    
    
    if(smartBoxClicked = false) {
        
        $('.smartBox').click(function() {
            $('.Box1, .Box2, .Box3, .Box4').draggable();
            $(this).animate({'top': '1%'}, 1000).animate({'left': '48%'}, 1000);
            smartBoxClicked = true;
        } else {
            $('.smartBox').click(function() {
                $(this).animate({
                    'top': '370px'
                }, 1000).animate({'left': '32.26%'}, 1000);
                smartBoxClicked = false;
        });
    });
    };
    
    /* .smartBox is a div with an image */
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: There's a lot of syntax errors

Comment: Your curly brackets don't match at all

Comment: `=` assigns values, `==` verifies values and also works with different data types, `===` strict value verification DOES NOT work with different data types

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it should be

```
var smartBoxClicked = false;    

if(smartBoxClicked == false) {
     $('.smartBox').click(function() {          
         $('.Box1, .Box2, .Box3, .Box4').draggable();
         $(this).animate({'top': '1%'}, 1000).animate({'left': '48%'}, 1000);
         smartBoxClicked = true;
     }); 
}else {
     $('.smartBox').click(function() {
        $(this).animate({
           'top': '370px'
        }, 1000).animate({'left': '32.26%'}, 1000);
        smartBoxClicked = false;
     });
};
```

"=" is for assign value, "==" should be for compare and also your curly brackets didn't match.

Comment: Can't believe I didn't see that... :D Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In this situations using a toggle class is very easy:

```
.animated{
   top: 1%;
   left: 48%;
 }
 .smartBox
 {
    transition-duration: 1s;
 }
```

And Jquery:

```
$('.smartBox').click(function() {
        $(this).toggleClass('animated');
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea, I might even switch to toggleClass =]

Comment: You welcome. If you want continue your way, you do not need `if(smartBoxClicked == false)` . It is faster and cleaner: `if(!smartBoxClicked)` .